# I am working as a freelancer (interior designing) in India . Do I have to register as a business?

Tags: india, business

I have recently been appointed as an interior designer for a Europe-based company. Although my income has not been fixed, do I have to register as a business in India? Can I print my visiting cards solely based on my name and qualifications instead of a company as such?

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict need to do that, you can consider yourself to be consulting, a 10% of your payment will be withheld and paid as tax by the company, you can deduct up to 60% of your income as expenses and pay tax on the rest (factoring the tax deducted at source). In another approach, you could register for service tax and charge service tax on your invoice and pay to the service tax department, the tax calculations are similar to above. It will be good if you speak to a chartered accountant and get more clarity.

As for business card, you could print it with your name and qualification, there are no restrictions on that.